# How to expand a wx.StaticBox horizontally?

Tags: python, wxpython, boxsizer

I am having troubles expanding a `StaticBox`.

Here is the code i am using:

```
self.images_area = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, '')
self.sizerBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
self.sizerBox.Add(self.images_area, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
self.SetSizer(self.sizerBox)
```

It appears to be working vertically however it does not expand horizontally (which I would have thought the opposite since I used `wx.HORIZONTAL` in the BoxSizer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
self.sizerBox.Add(self.images_area, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
```

You have some indications in the [wxPyWiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/UsingSizers) (point 8) of how EXPAND and the proportion parameters work to give the behavior of your widget.